# Is it possible to introduce multi threading in dotnet without explicity creating new threads?

Tags: sql, multithreading, parallel-processing, reentrancy

I have a loop of several hundred items which need to be processed.

Each item is processed by conditionally setting a global SQLConnection where upon the item is processed using this SQLConnection as part of the processing.

For this reason it is vital that none of these items is allowed to be processed in parallel.

I appreciate that this is not good design and I hope to rectify it as soon as is practical.

However it would seem that despite my best efforts, this code is experiencing some form of multi-threading. Somehow one of these tasks has thrown an exception.

This exception is the violation of a foreign key constraint, but indicates that it was operating against a SQLConnection which it has no business connecting to.

Naturally I have concerns about this, however to my knowledge there is no multi threading code in this app.

I wonder **Is it possible to introduce multi threading without explicitly creating new threads**

EDIT:

- VB.Net 3.5SP1
- Console App + Class Libraries
- Occasionally Calls out to web services
- Makes SQL calls
- not much of anything else. No Winforms, no WPF.

Comment: You might want to precise what kind of libraries besides sockets (WCF, WinForms, ...) you are using.

Comment: Webservices ? That sounds like sockets to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes - using System.Timers.Timer and/or System.Threading.Timer can cause the effect your describing. Whenever a timer ticks a new work item is queued in the ThreadPool - so essentially you have a multi threading program without explicitly creating new threads.

If the timer is AutoReset (remains enabled after elapsed has been called) you might cause another call to the same handler concurrently.

Comment: Interesting. No direct references to that class. However there are calls to System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000). Could this cause similar?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively tasks (ie Task objects) are not called threads, but are. Tasks are commonly found near lambda expressions, check if you have any.

Oh, and async sockets too and all the other async IOs.

BUT:

Instead of trying to avoid multithreading at all cost, wouldn't it be easier to lock ? Sorry if the question is naive, I may miss something.

Comment: Good suggestions - upvoted. However no sockets being used in this code. And .Net 3.5 (should have mentioned that) so no tasks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you using pipes if you don't use sockets ? You mention a connection in your question.

Comment: sorry I mean a SQLConnection to a DB. There are several databases which might be chosen. All with similar structure. I have amended my question to reflect this.

Comment: I am no SQL expert in C# at all, but it is likely that the API has asynchronous events. I.E. when you perform a request, make sure you get the result by doing a blocking call, not by specifying a callback.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the others that have been mentioned: parallel extensions (PLINQ and task parallel library).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your code is called from a 3rd party library. By using events another library can call your code - from as many threads as it like.
I suggest you check the code that invoke the code that changes and make sure that there's no suspicious calls to your code.